Solidity: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.28+commit.7893614a.Emscripten.clang)

Hey all, sorry if this aint the right place, but I feel like I'm losing my mind.
I'm getting this error, which I've tried troubleshooting through searches and chatgpt and nothing has really worked, wondering if anyone can help.
Basically I used to be able to work with any contract, regardless of solidity version, without having to solc-install/solc-select each version a contract needed. But I had to format my disk. After importing my WSL stuff to my new setup, I get those red squirly lines everytime I open up a contract.
Tried reinstalling solc/solcjs,  but the issue remains. Anyone encountered this before?
